# Find a document that contains a specific value in an array but not if it's the last element

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

My current approach is:

```js
var v = 'Value';
Collection.find({arrayToLookIn: v}).forEach(function(obj) {
  if (obj.arrayToLookIn.indexOf(v) !== obj.arrayToLookIn.length - 1) {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

I was wondering if there's a way to specify such a rule in the `find()` call and do this without the inner check?

I've looked through https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#match-an-array-element but didn't spot what I seek.

First question, please be gentle :)

Comment: I don't think this is possible in a regular query unless the index is known in advance. However if the objective is to "keep it in mongo" and get back just the items you want, it should be possible using an aggregation pipeline instead of a regular find query.

Comment: @Semicolon Of course it's possible and in this case probably a little more efficient to do with standard query `$where` than the aggregation framework, as that does not "presently" have an efficient way of exluding the last array element. Though that will soon change.

Comment: Interesting, @Blakes. I'd always had it in my head that $where wasn't available in regular queries for some reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### What you can do now

You want [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/), which can use JavaScript evaluation to match the document. So here you ask the evaluating code to test each array element, but not the last one:

```js
Collection.find({
    "arrayToLookIn": v,
    "$where": function() {
        var array = this.arrayToLookIn;
        array.pop();                    // remove last element
        return array.some(function(el) { return el == 'Value' });
    }
})
```

Note that as it is JavaScript sent to the server the "Value" needs to be specified in that code rather than using a variable. You can optionally contruct the JavaScript code as a "string" to join in that variable as a literal and submit that as the argument to `$where`.

Note that I'm leaving in the basic equality match, as `$where` cannot match using an index like that can, and therefore it's job is to "filter" out the results where the match is on the last element, and not test every single document to find whether it is even there at all.

---

### Better Future Way

For the curious, as of the present MongoDB 3.0 release series there is not a really efficient way to do this with the aggregation framework, so the JavaScript evalution is the better option.

You would presently need to do something silly like find the last element in a `$group` after `$unwind` and then `$match` out the value after another `$unwind`. It's not efficient and prone to error where the value exists more than once.

Future releases will have a `$slice` operator which could be used like this with `$redact`:

```js
Collection.aggregate([
    // Still wise to do this as mentioned earlier
    { "$match": { "arrayToLookIn": v } },

    // Then only return if the match was not in the last element
    { "$redact": {
        "$cond": {
            "if": {
                "$setIsSubset": [
                    [v],
                    { "$slice": [
                        "$arrayToLookIn",
                        0,
                        { "$subtract": [ { "$size": "$arrayToLookIn" }, 1 ] }
                    ]}
                ]
            },
            "then": "$$KEEP",
            "else": "$$PRUNE"
        }
    }}
```

Where [`$setIsSubset`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/) does the comparison of the array which has had it's last entry removed via `$slice` by only returning elements from `0` to the [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) minus `1`.

And that should be more efficient than `$where` as it uses native coded operations for the comparison, when the next release that has that `$slice` for aggregation becomes available.

Not to mention `$unwind` also has an option to include the index position in future releases as well. But it's still not a great option even with that addition.

Comment: Learned a lot from this, seems to be a nice and simple enough approach! Thanks a lot :)